# SSH on Linux Debian

Tags: debian, ssh

I have a Debian system running as a server in my office and I am trying to set up SSH on it so that I can connect to it from home.

But I am having problems.

From my computer at home I try the following in a terminal on my private computer when trying to connect to the Debian server:

```
ssh root@213.89.115.231
```

But nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the `-vvv` switch to print more useful debugging information. In all likelihood, your port is not being forwarded from the office router to your server...

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information. What exactly have you tried so far? How have you "tried" to set up SSH on the server? Is the SSH daemon running? Can it accept external connection to `root`? Do you have a firewall? Is `213.89.115.231` a reachable address from outside your office's network? Do you need NAT configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file, add hostname and key file path. The detailed description can be found in [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews)